# highest possible value for elasticsearch max_terms_count

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to set [`index.max_terms_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-max-terms-count) setting to highest possible value for my index. How do it do that?

I couldn't find any documentation on the highest possible value for that setting.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be **2147483647**.

I found it out by looking into [elasticsearch source on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) and then confirming it by making a PUT settings call on a test elasticsearch index.

- Turns out the `max_terms_count` setting is implemented as a Java `Integer` (`MAX_TERMS_COUNT_SETTING` member in `org.elasticsearch.index.IndexSettings`).
- The highest value for a Java `Integer` is 2147483647 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).
- **Quick evidence:**

  - Using the [PUT index setting API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/indices-update-settings.html), I set the setting to `2147483647` and it was successful;
  - however, when I set it to `2147483648` it threw an exception `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Failed to parse value [2147483648] for setting [index.max_terms_count]')`.